Finding columns with large NaN sum pandas
I'm working with a DataFrame and I needed to identify columns with large sum of NaN.
print(df.isnull().sum(axis = 0))
Id                 0
MSSubClass         0
MSZoning           0
LotFrontage      259
LotArea            0
                ... 
MoSold             0
YrSold             0
SaleType           0
SaleCondition      0
SalePrice          0
Length: 81, dtype: int64

I tried this code but there's 81 columns so I can't see other columns. Is there a way to present columns with NaN value only.

Just compare with 0? (>0)

Something like df.isnull().sum(axis = 0) > 0? Or, since that will be a boolean series, s = df.isnull().sum(axis = 0); print(s[s > 0])?

@9769953 oh it worked thanks

@Henry answer your question and close it if the comments helped you

To show columns with NaN >0:
s = (job.isnull().sum(axis = 0))
print(s[s>0])

